# JFrame acting strangely. Sporadically displays JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

Its hard to explain so I whipped out my phone and video'd the problem i'm having:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdOeNdE8W2Q

Simply put, the image (border at the bottom you can see, implemented as JLabel) should remain there at all times, but instead appears for 1 second, disappears and then flashes sporadically.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;

public class WebcamPanelExample extends JFrame {
    
    static Webcam webcam;
    static JFrame window;
    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        window = new JFrame("Test webcam panel");
        
        Dimension[] nonStandardResolutions = new Dimension[] {
                WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize(),
                };

        webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.setCustomViewSizes(nonStandardResolutions);
        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize());
        
        WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        panel.setFPSLimited(false); 
        panel.setFillArea(true); 
        window.add(panel);

        ////////////

        BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("F:/DATA/images/image_area.png"));
        JLabel guiBorder = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( image2 ));
        guiBorder.setSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
        guiBorder.setLocation(0, 0);
        window.add( guiBorder );
        
        ///////////
        
        Button button = new Button("Do Something");
        button.setSize(new Dimension(200,32));
        button.setLocation(540, 670);
        window.add(button);
        
        ///////////
        
        window.setComponentZOrder(button, 0);
        window.setComponentZOrder(guiBorder, 1);
        window.setComponentZOrder(panel, 2);
        
        ///////////
        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.validate();
        window.setSize(1280,720);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

In addition, if it matters:

- Using https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture for the webcam library.
- Using Windows 8 64bit but Java 32bit (need to for some things to work)

Any ideas on potential causes of the problem?

### Edit (By Andrew Thompson)

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
 import javax.sound.sampled.*;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.io.File;

 class AcceleratePlayback {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int playBackSpeed = 3;
     File soundFile;
         if (args.length>0) {
             try {
                 playBackSpeed = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.exit(1);
             }
         }
         System.out.println("Playback Rate: " + playBackSpeed);

         JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
         chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
         soundFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

         System.out.println("FILE: " + soundFile);
         AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
         AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();

         int frameSize = af.getFrameSize();

         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] b = new byte[2^16];
         int read = 1;
         while( read>-1 ) {
             read = ais.read(b);
             if (read>0) {
                 baos.write(b, 0, read);
             }
         }
         System.out.println("End entire: \t" + new Date());

        //This is the important bit

         byte[] b1 = baos.toByteArray();
         byte[] b2 = new byte[b1.length/playBackSpeed];
         for (int ii=0; ii<b2.length/frameSize; ii++) {
             for (int jj=0; jj<frameSize; jj++) {
                     int b3=0;  
             for (int kk = 0; kk < playBackSpeed; kk++){
              b3 = b3+(int)b1[(ii*frameSize*playBackSpeed)+jj+kk];  
             }
             b3 = b3/playBackSpeed;
             b2[(ii*frameSize)+jj] = (byte)b3;
             }
         }
        //ends here

         System.out.println("End sub-sample: \t" + new Date());

         ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b2);
         AudioInputStream aisAccelerated = new AudioInputStream(bais, af, b2.length);
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         clip.open(aisAccelerated);
         clip.loop(2*playBackSpeed);
         clip.start();

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit?");
     }
}
```

Comment: `window.setLayout(null);` That is the first thing you should fix.  The rest might fix itself.  BTW - For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). *"Its hard to explain so I whipped out my phone and video'd the problem i'm having"* Thanks, but no.  An SSCCE is all the explanation I require.

Comment: weel, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JLabel, before anything be sure that you moving setVisible for JFrame as last code line in constructor

Comment: aaaaaaach (we are) strange (this) cleaning squad, isn't it :-)

Comment: @mKorbel  You know - 'Great minds think alike' ;)

Comment: @Z-Mehn sorry hard to be answerable this question

Comment: Its a bit difficult because i have a lot of code. And the video was simply to show the resulting problem. Ill see what i can do.

Comment: @mKorbel *"hard to be answerable"*  (whispers) 1st I'd look into that whole 'layout' thing. ;)

Comment: @Z-Mehn answers are based on your effort, this question isn't about == YOU FORGOT TO ADD THIS MeTHoDs etc, then will be this nature, but .... :-)

Comment: What are you guys talking about? I gave a SSCCE... haha. Edited, thanks for the help.

PS: Layout is null because i want to specify x and y coords explicitly.

Comment: *"Layout is null because i want to specify x and y coords explicitly."*  I want a flying pony.  Point is, if you had the know-how to position & size the components by pixel, you might incorporate that into a (custom) layout manager.  For more info.(1) see [`setLayout(null)` is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374)  1) Some have, uncharitably, referred to it as a rant..  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can you explain the alternatives, i didnt really understand from that discussion. Ps. Leave out comments like "I want a flying pony." Its not fun to read that when youve been doing computer science assignments all day and just need a little help for the side/auxiliary stuff.

Comment: OK - have to admit I forgot to mention that is not an SSCCE in the usual sense.  You need to factor out 3rd party APIs and hot-link to images (by URL) or generate them in code.

Comment: _Any ideas on potential causes of the problem?_ Yes: `window.setLayout(null);`. That's your problem. Swing experts keep on telling you that. `setComponentZOrder`: use a `JLayeredPane` to handle stacking of components.

Comment: I have a view (of your app.) on-screen by replacing all the web-cam stuff with a `JPanel` & the image with a 400x100 black buffered image.  But I am not sure it it defines the layout you require.  Mind if I post it as an edit to the question (an addition to the end)?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I missed the notification.  See the edit, and adjust it to how you need it to look, edit the question (obviously) and let me know.  I am thinking that button needs to be in the `CENTER` of a `FlowLayout` in the `PAGE_END` of a `BorderLayout` (with an `EmptyBorder` as needed).  See also @GuillaumePolet excellent advice re. the `JLayeredPane`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapped to using JLayeredPane.

Workflow is essentially:

1. Create JFrame
2. Create JLayeredPane
3. Add JLayeredPane to JFrame
4. Create JPanels (as needed, i have three, one for webcam background, and two foreground layers for buttons etc)
5. Add your JPanels to the JLayeredPane. You set the z-index/order as you add them.

Complete example:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/jlayered-overlap-panel.shtml